# create new arrays from one array by first letter in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Let say I have an array that looks like this:

`array=("aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" "eee" "fff")`

and I want to split the array into two with ones that begin with a, b, or c, in one array and d, e, and f into another array.

How create new array's based on range of letters in the first character?

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like that:

```
array=("aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" "eee" "fff")
a1=()
a2=()
for v in "${array[@]}"
do
  if [[ "$v" =~ ^[abc] ]]
  then
    a1+=("$v")
  else
    a2+=("$v")
  fi
done
```

You can change the regular expression `^[abc]` to fit your needs. This regex says "if the text begins with a or b or c".

If you have several arrays to fill you may also use the `case` statement:

```
array=("aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd" "eee" "fff")
a1=()
a2=()
for v in "${array[@]}"
do
  case "$v" in
    a*|b*|c*)
      a1+=("$v")
      ;;
    d*|e*|f*)
      a2+=("$v")
      ;;
    *)
      printf -- "Unknown value: %s\n" "$v" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

The `case` statement is better if you have lots of simple conditions. A bunch of `if`s with regex is better if your have complex conditions because regex offers a much more powerful range of conditions than the ones in `case`.

PS. make sure to use quotes wherever needed in case your values contain whitespaces.

Comment: `a1+=($v)` seems more neat

Comment: @klashxx Thx for the tip. I have added quotes, though, because if `$v` has spaces it would add several entries to the array (note: it would add a single entry using `a[${#a[@]}]=$v` even without quotes).